# C# - Encrypting and Decrypting Using external RSA Keys

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, phpseclib

I'm working on a project that includes Encrypting and Decrypting between different parties.

The keys are generated using 'phpseclib' (https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/master/phpseclib/Crypt) on a remote server using RSA class.

The keys are in the following format:

Public:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGIAoGAUEAW3K4+77Q1XrbdE/Sat7l9LXcD8qUdDGzSMubWXARMj8xtaPnVj7Ec
81HU5lKbFO31tV9nPSNeApNkkZtQhxx0Gz2gQgiChiuhcmlmNdnzEXFFpwa+uo2i
fR5BLkNNy+qldhLqHg6yK7y0CrMKJUjfH2PKU+a5VectKkxPmDsCAwEAAQ==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Private:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIDHQIBAQKBgFBAFtyuPu+0NV623RP0mre5fS13A/KlHQxs0jLm1lwETI/MbWj5
1Y+xHPNR1OZSmxTt9bVfZz0jXgKTZJGbUIccdBs9oEIIgoYroXJpZjXZ8xFxRacG
vrqNon0eQS5DTcvqpXYS6h4Osiu8tAqzCiVI3x9jylPmuVXnLSpMT5g7AgMBAAEC
gYAb/L38aKh6XjDbXb2jFVQ3sxx3EQACbVVKo1e3LQY+YrMjSGsKS2TAbiMaNebF
7RPRFQfJ2gWSshDj0oCPg0U7WkEsFla5gIl3zJrVbeNnC9jyzZ/LgCnZIKiDcMXv
r0plq6HxcHJWcHecpKhfzvfmd26/U6DhL0kP54FWOf8AAQIJAIEyQC7c5gxXAgkA
5JFBPI+4/msCCD80lE3Y5/rVAgkApkPHeb9uqZsCCATuDv0RSFtXMIIB1jAfAgkA
uKLVRgl4zqkCCAae4CLoyAoxAggHXPQwQgmTOTAhAgkA6CnMpA9djC0CCQCBPmPS
IUuusQIJANRRQ8thKK4UMB8CCQC1KlBjMihEawIIGOMeNfJO+88CCHdqK2B+eQLs
MB8CCQC4HwiUnQVuLQIIaOjV3MfzdikCCHI4iaUvtcqGMB8CCQCUKg9il+fkPQII
VDo01M+WO+ECCEq17+pHX2OtMB8CCQCIZvXiOx/PbwIISPda/URHhf0CCFsVg61b
83D6MCACCQCwPqvRmoiStwIJAKF1mKSaJLn7Agh2FqM8iF6xmjAfAgkAlGuCK9lO
/IMCCCKkiWi0u1QDAggnJIDr4YyD3jAfAgkAhL2jhjw0DKsCCETMxeTdb1zhAghQ
V9S+12JvPzAfAgkA+6wy7oV1aocCCC3YBkcQpHzNAghOrrC+Nc3tgTAgAgkAxDf5
kZMTkUcCCQCqYJg5yWWyPQIIF1zKmIUwDGQwIAIJALbjlmSjpLg9AgkAqRV0P4sD
iMkCCAH9Ncvav/KFMCACCQDpSAEmE4WkowIIMH6/fmLgjXECCQCYz0JvH95z5DAh
AglCvzjdoEVfNPcCCT/8Id5LatUm5wIJCrp28jLZ/NOw
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I was trying to use the 'RSACryptoServiceProvider' for the  Encrypting and Decrypting but I was unable to find a way to convert the PEM format to the XML format the RSA Crypto Service Provider requires.

Any suggestion how can that be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can have phpseclib give you XML formatted keys by doing `$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);` and `$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_XML);`.